# Swift Equivalent of Objective-C Block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have the following Objective-C syntax:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^cropBlock)(UIImage *image);

- (void)cropAction {
    if (self.cropBlock) {
        self.cropBlock(self.imageScrollView.capture);
    }
}
```

I need the Swift equivalent syntax and I tried:

```
var cropBlock: (UIImage) -> Void 

private func cropAction() {
    if (self.cropBlock != nil) {
        self.cropBlock(self.imageScrollView.capture);
    }
}
```

But I got the error:

```
(UIImage) -> Void' is not convertible to 'UInt8
```

**What is the correct Swift representation?**

Comment: @Stuart I read this book.

Comment: @confile OK great! The answers & explanations to your questions lie within those pages; sometimes it's helpful to refer back to them when a specific question arises. I'd say that based on a couple of your questions it might help you to look back over optionals, type inference, properties and certain language basics (e.g. no need for semicolons at end of statements, parentheses in control flow statements, `self` to reference instance variables). Alternatively, you could start out with some simpler Swift coding to get to grips with the language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var cropBlock: ((UIImage?) -> Void)?

private func cropAction() {
    self.cropBlock?(self.imageScrollView.capture())
}
```

If `cropBlock` can be `nil`, it should be `Optional`.

And also if `self.imageScrollView.capture` can be `nil`, the first parameter of `cropBlock` should be `Optional`.

`self.cropBlock?(self.imageScrollView.capture())` is a shortcut of:

```
if let fn = self.cropBlock {
    fn(self.imageScrollView.capture())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it as a typealias in Swift:

```
typealias CropBlock = (image : UIImage) -> ()
```

For more information you can read the official documentation for typealias [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html).

Comment: This is probably appropriate, but I'd suggest that it should be `CropBlock`, as it is conventional in Swift for types to begin with a capital letter.